# Enable VisualForce Map Component apex:map

Tags: geolocation, google-map

I have found to my delight that there is now a [standard map component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_map.htm). However, it is apparently not enabled for my org.

[image: Visualforce maps are not enabled for your organization. Please contact your administrator.]

How do I enable them? Is this feature still in beta? All the listed features claim availability as of API Version 32. I did not see anything in the docs and although I found out this feature cannot be used in a Developer Edition, I am not using one, so that does not apply here.

[image]

Comment: hmm - spring 15 release notes say it should be enabled automatically; time for a support ticket to sfdc i would say

Comment: That's my next plan of action. Thanks @crop1645

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To opt in you need to go to Setup | Build | Customize | Maps & Location | Settings. There is a legal disclaimer and you can set enabled to true.

http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2014/11/spring-15-maps-opt-out.html

Comment: Hi, I am not getting Build option in setup for developer org. Can we enable it for developer org ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Use the setup search bar and look for maps.

Comment: I believe this (still) isn't available for developer orgs.