# Visualforce map component

Tags: visualforce, map

I wanted to use visualforce map component in our enterprise edition. I have checked that the service is enabled in our org. However everytime when i use apex:map and render the page. The page says "Visualforce maps are not enabled for your organization. Please contact your administrator.". I have created a case but they just say same bullshits.
Are there anyone who is having same problem ?
Here is my VF.

/apex/NearbyContacts?id=001D000000JRBet -->

```
 <apex:dataList value="{! Account.Contacts }" var="contact">
   <apex:outputText value="{! contact.Name }" />
 </apex:dataList> 

</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

```
<apex:repeat value="{! Account.Contacts }" var="contact">
<apex:mapMarker title="{! contact.Name }"
position="{!contact.MailingStreet},{!contact.MailingCity},{!contact.MailingState}">
    <apex:mapInfoWindow>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="font-weight: bold;">
            <apex:outputText>{! contact.Name }</apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
            <apex:outputText>
        {!contact.MailingStreet},{!contact.MailingCity},{!contact.MailingState}
      </apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>             
    </apex:mapInfoWindow>
</apex:mapMarker>
</apex:repeat>
```

And here is my error screenshot.

[image: MY Visualforce]

Comment: (1) Please, no profanity, as frustrated as you might be; (2) Just checking that you aren't developing in Developer Edition where VF maps aren't available (3) Presumably you saw this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67724/enable-visualforce-map-component-apexmap

Comment: Im not in developer org. I did not see that post.